# SQL Server 2016: How to restrict memory and CPU for specific database

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server 2016 Standard Ed on Windows 2016

We have an 8 core, 128GB machine (a VM, actually). We max this out for our prod db. (122GB for the instance, 8 cores for the instance)

We are setting up a 2nd db, to be on its own spindle set (slower disks), and do not want it to impact the prod db. This will be on the same VM (as we understand it, we can use the existing SQL license this way).

Must this 2nd db be served by its own SQL instance in order to:

- Restrict RAM consumed (to very little, just 4 or 8 GB)
- Restrict to 2 CPU cores

Or can we restrict this DB within the main instance?

(Note, Express Edition is not an option, our db will be over 10 GB)

Comment: Will this 2nd database ever be larger than 10GB?

Comment: To expand on Max's question in his comment, Express Edition is FREE as long as you are within the limits, including a 10 GB max database size. See the link below to help determine if Express Edition will satisfy your requirements, where you could have a new VM with the CPU and RAM configured https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2016#Cross-BoxScaleLimits

Comment: @JohnGHohengarten Express is not an option, enhancing OP in a moment...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure if your licensing would allow this, but you would get some degree of fine-tuned control by install a second SQL instance on the same host.

With that you can set the max memory of each instance individually, and you even have some ability to adjust CPU settings (processor affinity) for each (although [you should really understand this setting before messing with it](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1326759-149-1.aspx)).

The problem is that even in this scenario, if management asked me: "can you guarantee this won't impact the production database on the primary instance", I'd have to answer "no, I can't guarantee that." For that you'd want to run on an entirely separate VM.

Comment: I've got a VM performance killer that will hose the performance of all other VMs on the same host.

Comment: Unless you have separate disk arrays with separate controllers, that's a risk!

Answer (score 11):

You can't. There's no such thing as per-database restrictions because a query can cross multiple databases (think joins and fully qualified objects.)

SQL Server's Resource Governor in theory exists to support this, but it only works on things like CPU count, query workspace memory, and disk IO. It doesn't work on the buffer pool, so it still won't meet your needs.